# How do I run a rule when I reply to a message?

Tags: mac, rules, microsoft-outlook-2011

I want Outlook 2011 to automatically add a category **to messages I reply to**, when I reply to them. Is this possible?

I tried making a rule that runs on message replies, but I only saw these:
[image: The Outlook 2011 list of rule triggers]

And I don't think any apply to **"messages someone else sent that I've replied to".**

Comment: Is this what you are talking about - [Outlook 2007: Auto-assign categories on outgoing replies and forwards based on original message](http://www.juergentreml.de/archives/379)? Yes, I know it is for 2007, but may be useful information.

Comment: @CharlieRB no, that appears to be for **outgoing replies**. I want this to be for messages to which I have replied.

Comment: That is not the way your question reads..."add a category to messages I reply to, when I reply to them". You may want to clarify that in your question so you don't keep getting the same suggestions.

Comment: @CharlieRB also, that solution is Windows-only, and Office 2011 is Mac OS-only

Comment: @CharlieRB I'm sorry you didn't understand my wording, but I think I'm quite clear. I've made key phrases bold.

Comment: I know you are using Mac, even though you did not tag the question with it. The reason I did not post an answer is because I was offering info only, hence my comment stating; *"Is this what you are talking about...? Yes, I know it is for 2007, but may be useful information"*.  If I am to understand your comment correctly, you want Outlook to recognize incoming messages which belong to emails you have already replied to previously. Is that right?

Comment: @CharlieRB To directly answer your first comment: No, that is not what I am talking about. No, it is not useful information, because it does not apply at all to Office 2011.

Comment: @CharlieRB To directly answer your latest comment: Sort of. I want Outlook 2011 to recognize messages which have already come in (have been sitting in my inbox for an indefinite amount of time) to which I have just sent a reply (within the last few milliseconds, preferably). Your description might be a good workaround, but it's not my Plan A.